# MySQL - Stuck at Retrieving more than 300.000 row on a subquery

Tags: mysql, database

So.. i have a query which is look like this:

```
SELECT t.* FROM (select * from sp2010 LIMIT 300000) t WHERE t.something = 1;
```

It's work fine, but when i want to retrieve > 300.000 row, it is just got stuck and my MySQL server has stopped working.

What's going on?

Comment: how many columns do you have in your table? provide your table schema please

Comment: @Alex I have 3 column.

Comment: and `SHOW CREATE TABLE sp2010;` output is ... !?

Comment: You are getting these comments because there are many, many possibilities. You need to provide more detail.

Comment: @Mozahler It seems like i just need to add ORDER BY before LIMIT and it's working but i don't know why. sorry noob here.

Comment: you just need PK and indexes set up properly

Answer (score 0):

Just to optimize memory usage a bit you can do:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM sp2010 t
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT id 
   FROM sp2010 
   LIMIT 500000) t2 
ON t.id = t2.id
WHERE t.something = 1;
```

This way you will get less data when subquery and faster filter with `JOIN` indexed table against `WHERE` with temp dataset in memory

Comment: Thanks, this is improve my performance, but i still can't retrieve more than 300.000 row, and i don't know what's going on because there is no notification about the error. :(

Comment: dod you run it using any tool? there should be error message. and please provide your table schema

Comment: I run it on MySQL Command Line Client. 
Here is my table schema:
id_district int(3) DEFAULT NULL
urban_rural int(1) DEFAULT NULL
age int(2) DEFAULT NULL

The thing is.. this is just a Dummy database with a lot of row. I don't have any PK, all the data is generate.

Comment: why  `id_district` is not PK?

Comment: well, it could be become a PK if i change it.

Comment: please change it and add another index vs `something`